# Fitting a NN model on one-to-many function

Tags: regression, neural-networks, nonlinear-regression, stationarity, gaussian-process

Given $f(x) = y$ as a surjective (many-to-one) function, we know that $f^{-1} (y) = x$ is a one-to-many mapping for function $f^{-1}$. In my application, $x$ is a spatial data represented by a 2D image and $y$ is a time-series data over a fixed interval.

Building a neural network to represent $f(\cdot)$ has been trivial but to represent $f^{-1}(\cdot)$ is not as simple due to the nature of the function. Here I represent $f^{-1} (y) = x$ graphically.

[[image: <span class=]$f^{-1} (y) = x$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s159y.png)

In this pictorial representation, I actually need the green stippled line to touch all data points instead of taking the average. The challenge here is that $x$ is known to have residuals with Gaussian distribution, so a large dataset of $x$ will naturally form a Gaussian cloud and fitting a neural network model with of course fit something similar to the green stippled line.

Are there ways to represent a one-to-many function with a neural network? I've been reading on kernelization and was thinking of kernelizing $y$ but in my application $y$ is already a high dimensional data with 10-dimensions.

I appreciate your thoughts, thank you.

Comment: Since I asked this question more than a year ago, I have learnt a lot more and I'll include some information in the comment in case anyone finds it useful. For an ill-posed function, what you get when using a neural network to learn this ill-posed mapping will depend on the support between the variables. By the nature of regression itself, if you have high-dimensional data $(x, y)$ and you learn the inverse mapping $x = f^{-1}(y)$

Comment: ... the ill-posed dimensions with no data support will be averaged out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one has answered your question, I'll share my two cents, but I'm not too familiar with the methods used to solve inverse problems.

I don't think that this can be done the way you've described because $f^{-1}$ isn't actually a function (it fails the [vertical line test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_line_test)).

However, you might be able to fit a neural network to the inverse of each monotonic segment of the function $f$, if you know in advance *where* $f$ is monotonic.

Alternatively, you could treat $f^{-1}$ as a parameterised curve and fit it. What I mean by this is, fit a neural network *to each coordinate* of the curve $f^{-1}$ (in your example, the coordinates are $x$ and $y$). If this isn't clear, imagine a  circle with radius $1$ centred at $(x, y) = (0, 0)$. This isn't a function either, but the circle can be described by a set of two equations:

$$x = \cos(\theta)$$
$$y = \sin(\theta)$$

... for $\theta \in (0, 2\pi)$. The neural networks that you fit would replace the job of $\sin$ and $\cos$ in the example above. For an input, you'd have to use a pseudo-input (like $\theta$) but if you don't have it, you could treat it as an unknown as well, and place some kind of a prior on it (e.g. a gaussian process prior).

Comment: Thank you for the idea, I appreciate it, I'll give it more thoughts!